# csvsimple and tabular produces garbage

Tags: tables, csvsimple, badness

A simple example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
  \csvreader[separator=pipe,head to column names]{test.csv}{}{\foo&\bar\\}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

The `test.csv` file:

```
foo|bar|baz|
foo|bar|baz|
```

It should be *one* line but the first two vertical rules are longer than the table.

What's wrong? How can I fix it?
[image: result]

***EDIT***
Ruixi's answer doesn't work the following case. The `adatok.csv` file:

```
vara|varb|varc|vard|vare|
foo|bar|baz|foox|fooy|
foo2|bar2|baz2|foofoo|bazbar|
```

The LaTeX-file:

```
\documentclass[landscape,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|c|c|}
\csvreader[separator=pipe,head to column names]{adatok.csv}{}{\vara&\varb&\varc&\vard&\vare}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don’t think I fully understand your question. But removing the `\\` seems to solve your problem:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\begin{document}
\begin{tcbverbatimwrite}{test.csv}
foo|bar|baz|
foo|bar|baz|
\end{tcbverbatimwrite}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
  \csvreader[separator=pipe,head to column names]{test.csv}{}{\foo&\bar}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: foo and bar]

---

**Added**: With your new example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\begin{document}
\begin{tcbverbatimwrite}{test.csv}
vara|varb|varc|vard|vare|
foo|bar|baz|foox|fooy|
foo2|bar2|baz2|foofoo|bazbar|
\end{tcbverbatimwrite}
\begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\csvreader[separator=pipe,late after line=\\\hline,head to column names]{test.csv}{}{\vara&\varb&\varc&\vard&\vare}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: new example]

Comment: It seems in this simple case it works well. But I don't understand in my a little complicated case why not: without \\ causes error.

Comment: Could you please check my edit? Why doesn't work?

Comment: Your solution doesn't work too when you add a new line into (virtual) CSV file (for example copy the latest one).

Comment: @uzsolt Answer updated. :)

Comment: And how can do it when I want `\\[1cm]`? If I try `late after line=\\[1cm]` causes an error (Misplaced \noalign). Sorry for serial additions but I thought the simple case solves my problem.

Comment: I accepted and upvoted your answer because it's a solution to my original question. But if you've an idea to previous comment please say :)

Comment: @uzsolt Using `late after line={\\[1cm]\hline}` should work. The curly braces are needed to secure the option setting.

Comment: @ThomasF.Sturm Yes, you've right! If you would write this it to an answer I would vote it :) Many thanks!